# How to change StageWebview fontsize in flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, stagewebview

I am developing reader application in flex 4.6. I am using StageWebview to display my content.I want change the stagewebview fontsize when the user click my customized zoom button.
How can i do this..

My Code:  `webview.loadUrl("file:///mnt/sdcard/file.html");`

Answer (score 0):

you can set zoon in / out by using javascipt. Add below line in your file.html file in the script tag. or simply copy and paste below codes in your  tag. And call this methods by buttons.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var fontSize = 1;
   function zoomIn() 
   {
      fontSize += 0.1;
      document.body.style.fontSize = fontSize + "em";
   }
   function zoomOut() 
   {
      fontSize -= 0.1;
      document.body.style.fontSize = fontSize + "em";
   }
   </script>
```